# How do I create a SQLite database in monotouch for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, xcode4.2, monodevelop

I am new to iPad development. I have created two or three iPad applications in Objective C using Xcode 4. Now I want to create iPad applications in MonoDevelop tool using C#.

I want to create a basic database project, for that I need a basic tutorial, which uses a SQLite database. I searched on Google, but I didn't got any tutorial.

Comment: Not sure if Mono.Data.Sqlite namespace works for MonoTouch, but another possible approach is to use C#-SQLite, http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite

Comment: i need, database related tutorial for developing iPhone but using Monodevelop tool in C# language

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952306/how-to-create-database-and-table-in-sqlite-programatically-using-monotouch/7959026#7959026

Comment: http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/09/monotouch-with-sqlite-corporate.html

Comment: @jason: this code is in C#... i want run project in mono develop.. not in Visual studio..

Comment: MD is a C# IDE.  Craig's code that I linked to is a tutorial for MT/MD.  That is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: You asked this question 5 days ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access sqlite you have plenty of options, like

1. http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/ very useful and my prefered method
2. System.Data and Mono.Data.SQLite http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/system.data
3. EntityFramework for Mono http://www.taimila.com/entify/index.php (don't know if it is still in development)
4. Vici Cool Storage Here is a nice blog post about it http://blog.activa.be/index.php/2010/02/vici-coolstorage-orm-on-monotouch-made-simple/ and Vici's page http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home

and many others even Apple's CoreData see (http://www.sgmunn.com/?p=1) but i guess any of the above options is easier that that.

hope this helps to get you started

Answer (score 8):

I have tried both SqLiteClient and SqLite-net.  I would recommend you read the tutorial here:
[sqlite-net](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/)

For me, I just drop the Sqlite.cs file into my project and compile with it.

Then, using a tool of your choice, create a SQLite database and add it to your MonoTouch project being sure to set the build flag as "content".  Once you have the SQLite database in your project (put the file anywhere you like), you can access it in a **read-only** fashion...unless you do something similar to the code in the example below...which relocates the file to the user's personal folder for which your app (and your user) will have write privileges to.

If you need the user, at run time, to do **CRUD** operations against the database, you will need to include in your code something like this to copy the file to the user's personal folder:

```
using System.Linq;
using SQLite;

string personalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string dbName = "myDatabase.db";
string dbPath = Path.Combine ( personalFolder, dbName);

// in this example I will always delete and re-copy the db to the users personal folder...
// modify to suit your needs...
if (File.Exists (dbPath) {
    File.Delete(dbPath);
}
File.Copy (dbName, dbPath);
// note: myDatabase.db for this example is in the root project folder.

using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath)) {
    // query using Linq...
}
```

Hope that helps.